# Button positioning within BootStrap 5 div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have created a form with a single input, and the submit button, the problem is that I need everything to be on the same line for design reasons

This is the code I currently have

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="form-group">
                                    
    <label class="col-md-6" for="example-text">Añadir dirección IP</span></label>
       <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" class="form-control form-control-sm" 
placeholder="Buscar por Nombre" required></div> 
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10 text-white btn- 
 sm">Escribir IP</button>
   </div>
     </div>
```

[And visually it shows like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4u4c.png)

But for reasons of design and aesthetics of the platform I need it to look like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pF0FT.png)

I edit to respond to the companion of how it is displayed in my code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZC3tB.png)

thanks for all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**
You need to use display flex box. In bootstrap to use flexbox cupuk use class "d-flex"

**Code Solution**

```
<div class="row ">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex mt-3">
        <div class="form-group d-flex align-items-center me-2">
            <label class="col-md-6" for="example-text">Añadir dirección IP</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                placeholder="Buscar por Nombre" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10 text-white btn- 
     sm">Escribir IP</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: to get nice button size use class "btn-sm"

Answer (score 0):

you can use d-flex on parent container

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 d-flex">
        <div class="form-group">

            <label class="col-md-6" for="example-text">Añadir dirección IP</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="ip" name="ip" class="form-control form-control-sm"
                placeholder="Buscar por Nombre" required>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info waves-effect waves-light m-r-10 text-white btn- 
     sm">Escribir IP</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The result is not as expected...

Comment: I edited the original thread by adding as it is displayed in my code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).